# Linear regression correlation

Tags: regression, self-study, correlation

In a linear regression with several variables, a variable has a positive regression coefficient if and only if its correlation with the response is positive. ¿(TRUE OR FALSE)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

False - if theres enough positive correlation within the independent variables ($cor(X_i,X_j) > 0$), and they're all positively correlated with the dependent variable ($cor(Y,X_i) > 0$), you can have a situation where one variable has a positive $\beta$ and another has a negative one, especially if linear combinations of the $X$'s have explanatory power. Try regressing ten year interest rates on 3 year, 5 year, and 15 year for a clear example of this.

Comment: Thank you, @Emily ! So, the positive and negative β means that may be a correlation between the 2 variables?

Comment: If they're both positively correlated with $Y$, and their $\beta$'s have opposite signs like you describe, then the two are definitely correlated (if there are no other regressors).